# Map that associates operators with lambda functions

Tags: haskell, lambda, dictionary

I have a Haskell Map, containing strings as keys and some lambda functions as items .
Eg.:

```
-- List of supported Operators -> mapping with functions
ops = Map.fromList [("+", \x y -> x + y),
                    ("-", \x y -> y - x),
                    ("*", \x y -> x * y),
                    ("/", \x y -> y / x)]
```

I want to write a function that takes as input:

- A string representing an operator ["+", "-", "*", "/"]
- Two numbers

Based on the operator and the ops map, the function will evaluate the sum/subtraction/etc. of the two numbers .

I've tried something like:

```
(Map.lookup "+" a) 1 2
```

But it's not working .

The error is:

```
Top level:
    No instance for (Show (Integer -> Integer))
      arising from use of `print' at Top level
    Probable fix: add an instance declaration for (Show (Integer
    In a 'do' expression: print it

<interactive>:1:1:
    No instance for (Monad ((->) t))
      arising from use of `Data.Map.lookup' at <interactive>:1:1-
    Probable fix: add an instance declaration for (Monad ((->) t)
    In the definition of `it': it = (Data.Map.lookup "+" a) 1 2
```

... not very helpful for me.

Any suggestions ? Thank you !

Comment: Note that you can just do `[("+", (+)), ("-", (-)), ...]` (the operator in parens is called a section and does the same thing as your lambdas more neatly; it also works for infix application of functions and when either argument is fixed, e.g. `(\`mod\` 2)` or `(2/)`).

Comment: @delnan Although he has the arguments to `-` and `/` the "wrong" way round to do that.

Comment: @Dave: Yes, silly me. Still, no need for an explicit lambda: `flip (-)` and `flip (/)` :)

Comment: Thanks for your answers . Eventually I followed Bill's advice, and the things worked as I espected .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

lookup is of type `lookup :: Ord k => k -> Map k a -> Maybe a`.  The result is wrapped in a Maybe to indicate that the key may not be present in the map.

Here's a way to do it that will work:

```
runOp :: String -> a -> a -> b
runOp key x y = case lookup key ops of
                  Just op -> op x y
                  Nothing -> error ("Couldn't find operator: " ++ key)
```

This will bottom out if the key is not present.  You could also return an `Either` or `Maybe` result from runOp to accommodate the possibility that the key isn't present, but that's up to you.

Maybe is defined as follows:

```
data Maybe a = Just a | Nothing
```

that is, it either holds a result value or an empty value.  Like an existential philosopher, Haskell forces you to acknowledge the possibility of `Nothing`.

Comment: I'd leave out the bit about sections: given the way Andrei defined `ops`, it should be `flip (-)` and `flip (/)`.

Comment: Oh weird, you're right.  I hadn't noticed that they were flipped.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

First of all the error you showed is not caused by the code you showed. Your code causes the following error (in ghc):

```
Couldn't match expected type `t1 -> t2 -> t'
against inferred type `Data.Maybe.Maybe
```

That error is caused by the fact that `lookup` returns a `Maybe`. So you need to unwrap the `Maybe` first.

Answer (score 2):

```
import Control.Applicative

ops :: (Fractional a) => Map.Map String (a -> a -> a)
ops = Map.fromList [("+", (+)),
                    ("-", flip (-)),
                    ("*", (*)),
                    ("/", flip (/))]

apply :: (Fractional a) => String -> a -> a -> Maybe a
apply op x y = Map.lookup op ops <*> y <*> x
```

Because `lookup` returns a `Maybe a` (well, `Maybe (a -> a -> a)` in this case), there is no way to directly apply it to an `a`.  We can use `<*>` to pull the LHS out of the mote, apply it to the RHS, and inject it back into the monad.  (Or do it manually like Bill.)